# Godaddy: Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess setup on my clients site, they use godaddy

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

it worked fine on my MAMP but does not seem to work on the server

they have setup a subdomain like demo.example.com and the htaccess exists in the demo folder but I get 404 trying to get to page like demo.example.com/test but demo.example.com/test.php works fine so this tells me the htaccess is not work. does anyone know what I need to do to make this work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

1) Add this line into your .htaccess: `Options +FollowSymlinks`

2) Add leading slash before `$1`, e.g. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]`

**P.S.** There are some "rumours" that GoDaddy may not pick up changes in .htaccess file straight away.

I would also suggest to define custom 404 error handler (simple PHP script) that may help with debugging this (put this line into your .htaccess):

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

**404.php** (as simple as this)

```
<?php
Echo "404\n";
phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);
```

The details there *may* help identify the issue.

**UPDATE:**

We have a domain name & hosting that we do not use which is about to expire. So I have logged in and tested these rules myself. Got it working straight away. Here is the setup I have:

- Apache/1.3.33
- Hosting Configuration: 2.1
- PHP 5.x (did not bothered to check exact version)
- Data Center: US Regional

`.htaccess` was already present and had only 1 line 9possibly left over from the site that was there originally):

```
addhandler x-httpd-php5 .phtml
```

These lines were added to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I have created simple php file to check if it works. Called it `echo.php`. Then I have tried these URLs:

- `http://www.example.com/abcd` -- saw error page (as expected)
- `http://www.example.com/echo` -- saw my page -- echo.php (as expected)

The full physical path to the echo.php is: `/home/content/b/u/y/buyxxxxxxx/html/echo.php`; ftp/website root is `/home/content/b/u/y/buyxxxxxxx/html/`

Try this simple setup. DO not do anything complex until you solve this issue.

Comment: according to a page a saw on godaddy if its a new htacess file then it "can take upto an hour" but existing file should update right away. btw so far no luck

Comment: does the version of apache or php make a difference here ?

Comment: For such simple rules -- should not (especially PHP). What Apache version do you have there?

Comment: haha I don't think its appache  looks like Microsoft-IIS/6.0 ... crappy never worked with that before

Comment: We have 1 GoDaddy account that we do not use which is about to expire. So I have tested these rules there -- it works just fine -- I'm updating my answer to show the file contents and other details.

Comment: @LazyOne did you see my last comment ? I"m not sure it will make a diff based on that. so don't waste your time. Thanks for your help I would have been fighting a loosing battle there

Comment: Ah .. so it is IIS6? Sorry, I have misread that. You have to have some 3-rd party tool installed there to have redirects working (like [Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) for example -- it supports .htaccess syntax.

Comment: Hi.. I had tried with above simple rules but still it is not working and redirecting it to 404 page, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

This is right way of play with .htaccess on godaddy

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9348495/344480) might help you aswell:

Add this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

at the very top and give it a try.